# Hidden Communities description doesn't have margins

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, mobile-web, hidden-communities

On the mobile version of site, the description for the Hidden Communities section doesn't have margins on the left or at the top:

> [image: hidden]

Comment: @Cai why `or`? if they for both: left *and* top.